# Is there a better way access a same-type enum value than a match?

Tags: rust, enums, match, traits

Is there a better way to access the contents of an Enum that in the various cases shares the same variable type?
At the moment I have solved it this way:

```rust
enum Token<'a> {
    Word(&'a str),
    Reserved(&'a str),
    Whitespace(&'a str),
}

impl<'a> ToString for Token<'a> {
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        match self {
            Self::Word(str) | Self::Reserved(str) | Self::Whitespace(str) => str.to_string(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If all enum variants have the same signature, you may want to move the innards into an outer struct, and have an enum just to specify the kind instead. `struct Token<'a> { span: &'a str, kind: TokenKind }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with this implementation. But you could (and maybe should) instead have

```
enum TokenKind {
    Word,
    Reserved,
    Whitespace,
}

struct Token<'a> {
  string: &'a str, 
  kind: TokenKind
}
```

This is more extensible, and less code duplication.

Comment: Thank u, I feel really stupid right now, I did this kind of implementation in another struct and I completely forgot that I can do it here too :'-)